# Software for converting .m3u to .mp3

Tags: software-recommendation, mp3, conversion

I have downloaded some of the music files which are in `.m3u` format and I want to convert it to `.mp3` format so that I can listen it in my mp3 player.

Is there any software or online converter available  for that?

Comment: m3u is a list of mp3 files, you can not convert them to mp3.

Comment: @KasiyA So i need to download them again 

Comment: Are you playing them now? if yes what is your player?

Comment: @KasiyA Yes, in vlc media player

Comment: ummm... Go to file and click save as to saving them as mp3. one by one :)

Comment: @KasiyA Ahha, it worked. Please add it as answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

m3u is a list of mp3 files, you can not convert them to mp3.

Instead you can go to Media menu from your player(VLC) and click Convert/Save to extracting them to single mp3 after playing `.m3u` list.

Or you can Import your `.m3u` list on VLC and then press list view(hint 1) and from mp3 list you can right-click and click Save...(hint 2) and select your devices to save location.

one by one. ;)

[image]

Or if you want to find their location simply right-click and select "Show Containing Directory" and copy all of them from opened location in your device.

[image]